# Linq, how can I do flexible sorting?

Tags: linq

I'm new to linq, now I need to do flexible sorting with sort parameter specified.
but

```
var query =
    from accessdoc in dt1.AsEnumerable()
     join content in dt2.AsEnumerable()
     on accessdoc.Field<string>("name") equals content.Field<string>("FileName")
    into docs
    orderby accessdoc.Field<DateTime>("CreateDate") descending //TODO: HOW TO SORT??
```

dose not meet the demand.
Can I be helped out here?

Comment: could you provide the whole LINQ expression? why does not "order by CreateDate" work for you?

Comment: it works for me, but which is not flexible, i need to do as parameter specified, like how if param passed in is - "id desc"?

Comment: var query =
    from accessdoc in dt1.AsEnumerable()
     join content in dt2.AsEnumerable()
     on accessdoc.Field<string>("name") equals content.Field<string>("FileName")
    into docs
    orderby accessdoc.Field<DateTime>(MY_PARAMETER) descending

Comment: how can i know whether is desc or asc? datetime or string?

Comment: you could take the field name and sort direction as 2 separate parameters, and based on sort direction, create your query using either `orderby accessdoc[fieldName]` or `orderby accessdoc[fieldName] descending`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since linq is late binding you can do your query and then apply your sort separately.  If you can split up how you do the sort parameter slightly, you could do something like this:  (this code hasn't been compiled, so please bear with me)

```
public enum SortDirection
{
   Ascending = 0,   //default value
   Descending = 1
}
```

now if you pass in the linq expression and the direction, you could do something like this:

```
public IQueryable<MyObject> GetWithSort(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<MyObject, TKey>> sortExpression, SortDirection direction)
{
    var results = from accessdoc in dt1.AsEnumerable()
         join content in dt2.AsEnumerable()
         on accessdoc.Field<string>("name") equals content.Field<string>("FileName")
        into docs
        select...;

   if (direction == SortDirection.Descending)
      return results.OrderByDescending(sortExpression);

   return results.OrderBy(sortExpression)
}
```

select... will have to be replaced with however you are selecting your objects out of the linq statement.

Comment: sorry...I forgot to rate.. do it now.. :)